# JApplet/JPanel not receiving KeyListener events!

Tags: firefox, applet, jpanel, fedora, keylistener

I cannot get my JPanel within my JApplet to receive keyboard events. I CANNOT FATHOM why!

**Note that...**

1. Clicking the panel (with mouse) before typing makes no difference. This is by far the most common advice I see given on the Net.
2. I have tried using the 'low-level' java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher interface. That makes no different either!
3. However, if I use Applet instead of JApplet, then the Applet DOES receive keyboard events. But even here, the moment I add a Panel to this Applet (the Panel is really where all my app/painting logic is), I once again stop receiving kb events (in my Panel)!
4. Now, I cannot simply use Applet (instead of JApplet) because, among other things, its onPaint gets a Graphics (instead of a Graphics2D object). So, #3 is NOT a solution for me.
5. Things work like a charm in AppletViewer that comes with JDK.

I desperately need someone's help here. Spent last 2-3 days trying all kinds of permutations I don't even recall now.

**My platform details:**

1. Firefox 3.5.3
2. Fedora 11 on x86 (with latest updates/patches)
3. Java Plugin: tried both of these, made no difference.

   3.1 IcedTea Java Web Browser Plugin 1.6 (fedora-29.b16.fc11-i386)

   3.2 jdk1.6.0_16/jre/plugin/i386/ns7/libjavaplugin_oji.so
4. Used the above jdk1.6.0_16 to compile my applet source.

Here's my code. Will greatly appreciate to hear from my fellow programmers... as I'm completely stuck!

Thanks,

/SD

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


class MyAppletKeyListener implements KeyListener, MouseListener {

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("panel:keyPressed" + e.getKeyChar());
  }
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  }
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("panel:keyTyped" + e.getKeyChar());
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("panel:mouseClicked");
  }
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
}


public class TestApplet extends JApplet implements MouseListener {
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("applet:init");

    MyAppletKeyListener listener = new MyAppletKeyListener();

    // Panel related
    // Note: I'd like this red panel to handle 
    // all my keyboard and mouse events.
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(new JButton("test"));
    panel.add(new JButton("test2"));
    panel.setFocusable(true);
    panel.requestFocus();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(200, 0, 0));
    panel.addKeyListener(listener);
    panel.addMouseListener(listener);

    // applet related
    // Note: Added this only for debugging. I do NOT want
    // to handle my mouse/kb events in the applet.
    addMouseListener(this);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(panel);

  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("applet:mouseClicked");
  }
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet id="myApplet" code="TestApplet.class"
        width="425"
        height="150" >
    </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works for me using Applet Viewer, Win XP, Java 1.6.0_16.

Comment: Hey, Nick, as I said in Note #5 above, it works fine for me too in Applet Viewer.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I just tested it in browser, FF3.5, IE8 and Chrome 3 under XP and they all worked ok for me. It looks like it's pretty much isolated to be a plugin issue for Fedora.

Answer (score 3):

I found this on the net, and it solves the issue for me:

> As for the fact that KeyListener does
>   not work for JApplet as it does for
>   Applet you should use the
>   KeyEventDispatcher interface.
>
> ```
> public class AppletMain extends JApplet implements
> ```
>
> java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher
>
> Furthermore you have to set the
>   KeyboardFocusManager to the Panel
>
> ```
> KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(this);
> ```
>
> Afterwards override the
>   dispatchKeyEvent function of the
>   interface:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e);
> ```
>
> This allows you to catch the KeyEvents
>   as it is done with KeyListener.

Answer (score 2):

I investigated the problem connected to my current project and explored some problems with focusability of JApplet class. 
It is because why `setFocusable(true);`decided the problem.
You also may eventually need to add focus-capture call such as `requestFocusInWindow();` to make it work propertly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the sun-java-6 packages and the openjdk packages in both Ubuntu 9.04 and 10.10 with firefox version 3.6.11 and 3.6.14. I've discovered two workarounds: use Applet rather than JApplet, or implement a MouseListener which calls "requestFocus()" in the mousePressed(..) function.